# Appending text to a p with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form text and I want to append what I type in an existing paragraph called "one". Whan I press a "button1" I want the existing text from the paragraph to be deleted, and after that to add the text from the formtext.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, please check [this](http://codepen.io/Serse/pen/XmWGKo) codepen and help me!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('.one').remove();
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('.one').append(toAdd);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `.remove`, call `.empty()` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button1').click(function() {
        $('.one').empty();
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.one').append(toAdd);
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of `empty()` and `append()`, why not `text()` or `html()`

Comment: @Tushar The question is about appending, if you empty() an object first, you can append as many times as you need. If you use text() you will replace the content every time. Usage of course depends on the developer :)

Comment: The only problem I have right now is that after I generate a random quote and add some text, the quote doesn't dissapear and the text goes under the quote

Comment: @RaduSersescu because you generate it into `<span class = "saying"></span><br><span class = "author"></span>` and not into `<p class="one text-center">...</p>`.

Comment: @RaduSersescu just change `$('.one').empty();` to `$('.one, .saying, .author').empty();`

Comment: @WellBloud that was it, forgot to empty those classes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are removing it first:

```
$('.one').remove();
```

That makes it not exist! Remove it. Change your code this way:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  $('.one').empty();
  var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
  $('.one').html(toAdd);
});
```

Comment: Then also need to use `html()` instead of `append()` to add new data in the paragrahp

Comment: `$('.one').remove();
That makes it not exist! Remove it.` This confuses, `remove(); ... Remove it!`

Comment: even after i change html with append, If I generate a random quote and after that I try to add something, it doesn't work